# Annotated field is not accessible from prefetched model

Tags: sorting, django-models, annotations, django-queryset, prefetch

I have two models as:

```
class Training(models.Model):
    """Training records Model."""


class PersonTraining(models.Model):
    """Saves the trainings, the employee has completed or is enrolled in."""

    employee = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='records', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    training = models.ForeignKey(Training, related_name='person_training', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in the **get_queryset** method of the **PersonTrainingView(viewsets.ModelViewSet)**
i have annotated **Training** model's objects with **'average_rating'** and **'is_top_rated'** fields

and then i have prefetched the training model in PersonTraining queryset as:

```
person_training_queryset = person_training_queryset.prefetch_related(
                              Prefetch('training', queryset=annotated_trainings)
                           )
```

The issue is that i need to sort the **PersonTraining** queryset based on the annotated fields of the prefetched **Training** model as:

```
person_training_queryset = person_training_queryset.order_by('-training__is_top_rated', '-training__average_rating')
```

But it is not accessible during execution in the **get_queryset** method and throws,

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword`

kindly suggest a solution.

***note:*** I am not annotating PersonTraining queryset with **'average_rating'** and **'is_top_rated'** fields, as i need to apply distinct on the PersonTraining queryset
and it will through

`'Error: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.'`

Answer (score 0):

+1 Faced the same problem. The queryset that I'm going to use in Prefetch class works as expected with annotated fields by itself, but not in final queryset where it is prefetched. So nested objects haven't annotated attributes which are needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).